# Question about custom conversion of "lambda []void ()->void"

Tags: c++, class, c++11, lambda, std-function

`TestCase2` and `TestCase3` can compile normally. However, in `TestCase1` I get the following error:

```
E0312, Custom conversion from "lambda []void ()->void" to
       "EventHandler" is not appropriate.
```

Why am I getting this error? I want to know how to solve it.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class EventHandler
{
    std::function<void()> _func;

public:
    int id;
    static int counter;

    EventHandler() : id{ 0 } {}
    EventHandler(const std::function<void()>& func) : _func{ func }
    {
        id = ++EventHandler::counter;
    }
};

int EventHandler::counter = 0;

int main()
{
    EventHandler TestCase1 = []() {};
    EventHandler TestCase2([]() {});
    EventHandler TestCase3 = static_cast<std::function<void()>>([]() {});
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error?

The lambda `[]() {}` is not the same as `std::function<void()>`. That means

```
decltype([]() {}) != std::function<void()>
```

and it has to be implicitly or explicitly converted.

At the line

```
EventHandler TestCase1 = []() {};
```

[copy initialization take place](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), where compiler first has to convert the lambda to a `std::function<void()>` and then a `EventHandler` object. Compiler can not do double implicit conventions.

Therefore, you need to be explicit here, like in `TestCase3` for instance.

---

> I want to know how to solve it.

One way is to provide a templated constructor (if you willing to)

```
#include <type_traits> // std::is_convertible_v

class EventHandler
{
    std::function<void()> _func;
public:

    template<typename Func> EventHandler(Func func)
        : _func{ func }
    {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<Func, decltype(_func)>
                                            , "is not valid arg!");
        // ....
    }
    // or in C++20 with <concepts> header
    // template<typename Func> EventHandler(Func func)
    //     requires std::convertible_to<Func, decltype(_func)>
    //  : _func{ func }
    // { ... }
};
```

Now you can

```
EventHandler TestCase1 = []() {}; // works
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/7h7vYM9PK)

Answer (score 4):

##### Case 1

Here we consider the statement:

```
EventHandler TestCase1 = []() {};//this is copy initialization
```

the above statement uses copy initialization.

And from [copy initialization's documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

> In addition, the implicit conversion in *copy-initialization* **must produce `T` directly from the initializer**, while, e.g. *direct-initialization* **expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of `T`'s constructor.**

And as `EventHandler` can't be directly produced from the initializer lambda on the right hand side, the first case of `TestCase1` isn't allowed in accordance wirh the above quoted statement.

---

##### Case 2

Here we consider the statement,

```
EventHandler TestCase2([]() {});//this is direct initialization
```

the above uses direct initialization and since there is an implicit conversion available(using the **converting constructor**), this time it is allowed according to the above quoted statement.