# Why is class with std::function argument in constructor not implicitly convertible to callable

Tags: c++, lambda, implicit-conversion, std-function

Here is a simplified class I have:

```
class Event {
private:
    std::function<void()> m_func;
public:
    Event(std::function<void()> func)
        : m_func(func)
    {}
};
```

I cannot do implicit conversions on it:

```
void foo() {}

int main() {
    Event evt = foo; //error
    evt = []() {}; //error
}
```

Why is this? `std::function` by itself is implicitly convertible to a callable object: `std::function<void()> func = []() {}`.

Comment: Duplicate: [Question about custom conversion of "lambda [\]void ()->void"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400779/question-about-custom-conversion-of-lambda-void-void). Because *"Compiler can not do double implicit conversions."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because only one user-defined implicit conversion is allowed in one conversion sequence.

For `Event evt = foo;`, two user-defined conversions are required. One is from function pointer to `std::function`, one is from `std::function` to `Event`.

Similarly for `evt = []() {};`, one user-defined conversion is from lambda to `std::function`, one is from `std::function` to `Event`, are required.

You can apply [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) instead of [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), or perform some explicit conversion in advance. E.g.

```
Event evt (foo);                      // direct initialization
evt = std::function<void()>([]() {}); // convert lambda to std::function in advance
```

Comment: If you're curious about _why_ only one user-defined conversion is allowed in an implicit conversion sequence, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337198/why-user-defined-conversions-are-limited) gets into the motivation for the policy

Comment: I see. Thanks for showing alternate ways of initialization too.